# Creating a SharePoint sub site programatically from an MVC application

Tags: mvc

I have an SP site collection.

My requirement is to create a **sub site** in this site collection from an **MVC application**. When I enter the name of the site and click on '**Create**' button from MVC site, a sub site with entered name should be created in site collection.

Comment: Where your MVC application is hosted?

Comment: SharePoint version ?

Comment: @ Aakash Morya: application is hosted in IIS.

Comment: Your SharePoint and MVC are hosted on the same server?

Comment: no both are on different servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using [Client Object Model C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798388.aspx). Add `.dll`s from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll/) in your MVC project.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll
```

[Here](https://sharepointschool.wordpress.com/2010/10/01/client-object-model-create-a-new-sub-site/) is an example. Don't forget to pass a credential.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
    using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities;

    private void CreatenewSite()
            {
                string SiteDescription = “This is my first site creation using Client Object Model.”;
                int SiteLanguage = 1033;
                string SiteTitle = “My first SharePoint School Site”;
                string SiteUrl = “miniSharePointSchool”;
                bool SitePermissions = false;
                string mywebTemplate = “STS#0”;

                ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(“http://SharePointSchool/“);

                clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");

                //Retreive the web from the Client Context. This web is the root web by default.
                Web oWebsite = clientContext.Web;

                //Create a new webCreateInformation object to specify the properties of the new site being created.

                WebCreationInformation webCreateInfo = new WebCreationInformation();
                webCreateInfo.Description = SiteDescription;
                webCreateInfo.Language=SiteLanguage;
                webCreateInfo.Title= SiteTitle;
                webCreateInfo.Url=SiteUrl;
                webCreateInfo.UseSamePermissionsAsParentSite= SitePermissions;
                webCreateInfo.WebTemplate=mywebTemplate;

                //Adding a new site under the root web

                Web oNewWebsite = oWebsite.Webs.Add(webCreateInfo);

                // Retreiving the server properties to the client context. Here we are retreiving the web server url and the time it was created.

                clientContext.Load(oNewWebsite,
                    Website => Website.ServerRelativeUrl,
                    Website => Website.Created);

                // Executes the query to retreive the required information from the server.
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                Console.WriteLine(“Site Created on: ” + oNewWebsite.Created);
                Console.WriteLine(“with Site Title: ” + oNewWebsite.Title);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
```

Comment: This code will work if this application and SharePoint Application are hosted on same server. But the user has specified his MVC application is hosted on different server.

Comment: Nope! It must work from different server. Just the user will have to pass a credential. **CSOM is the one & only way to talk with SharePoint from outside**

Comment: Yes @Atish, I was worried about the authentication part only :-)

Comment: @ Atish: I got an error 'The type or namespace name 'NetworkCredential' could not be found '.I googled and added the Runtime.dll. But it throws an error Runtime.dll namespace can't be found. I have added the refernce for Runtime.dll.

Comment: Add `System.Net` dll in reference

Comment: @Atish: can we use the same for office 365 credentials? It is not working for o365.

Comment: you can. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/25445631/1294606